# Render a Component passed in as a Prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

How can I render a `StyledComponent` that's passed in as a prop?

I'm passing in a `Spinner` component to my `BarComponent` as a prop to render. I tried using `{this.props.icon}` in my `BarComponent` in the following example but it gave me an error instead:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, render, attrs, componentStyle, displayName, foldedComponentIds, styledComponentId, target, withComponent, warnTooManyClasses, toString}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

How can I fix this?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyledIcon } from 'styled-icons';
import { Spinner } from 'styled-icons/fa-solid';

interface BarComponentProps {
  icon: StyledIcon,
  name: string
}

class BarComponent extends Component<BarComponentProps> {
  render() {
    return (
      // How to render a StyledComponent passed in as a prop?
      // In this example it should result in something like:
      // <div><Spinner /> - {this.props.name}</div>
      <div>{this.props.icon} - {this.props.name}</div>
    );
  }
}

class FooComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return <BarComponent icon={Spinner} name='Baz' />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `createElement()`, like so:

```
<div>{React.createElement(this.props.icon)} - {this.props.name}</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

don't pass class name but pass component instead:

```
class FooComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return <BarComponent icon={<Spinner />} name='Baz' />;
  }
}
```

This is a composition pattern.

If you even handled it with passing just class name(say with `React.createElement`) it would not be very useful in case you need to provide additional props(like parameters or `style`). So composition is much more flexible here

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass it as children.

```
<BarComponent name='Baz' >
<Spinner />
</BarComponent>

class BarComponent extends Component<BarComponentProps> {
 render() {
  return (
  // How to render a StyledComponent passed in as a prop?
  // In this example it should result in something like:
  // <div><Spinner /> - {this.props.name}</div>
  <div>{this.props.children} - {this.props.name}</div>
);
}
}
```

Comment: it is not required to pass components a children. any prop can contain children elements